# RecyclerView: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, indexoutofboundsexception, screen-rotation

Our QA has detected a bug: when rotating the Android device (Droid Turbo), the following **RecyclerView-related crash** happened:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:
>       Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 2(offset:2).state:3

To me, it looks like an internal error inside RecyclerView, as I can't think of any way of this being caused directly by our code...

Has anyone encountered this problem?

What would be the solution?

A brutal workaround could be perhaps to catch the exception when it happens and re-create the RecyclverView instance from scratch, to avoid getting left with a corrupted state.

But, if possible, I would like to understand the problem better (and perhaps fix it at its source), instead of masking it.

The bug is not easy to reproduce, but it is fatal when it happens.

The full stack-trace:

```
W/dalvikvm( 7546): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41987d40)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546): Process: com.oblong.mezzedroid, PID: 7546
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 2(offset:2).state:3
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3382)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3340)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1810)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1306)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1269)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:523)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at org.liboid.recycler_view.RecyclerViewContainer$LiLinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(RecyclerViewContainer.java:179)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:1942)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:2237)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at org.liboid.recycler_view.LiRecyclerView.onLayout(LiRecyclerView.java:30)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14946)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4651)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14946)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4651)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14946)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4651)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at com.oblong.mezzedroid.workspace.content.bins.BinsContainerLayout.onLayout(BinsContainerLayout.java:22)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14946)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4651)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14946)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4651)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14946)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4651)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14946)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4651)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14946)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4651)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14946)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4651)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14946)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4651)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14946)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4651)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2132)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1872)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 7546):    at andro
```

Comment: A question: How consistent is your repro? I know this is an error in google's code [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=1&q=77846&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&id=77846) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77232). But this can be avoided. So, is this happening on every rotate?

Comment: Hi. It happens only rarely, but when it happens, it is fatal to the app.

Comment: Thanks for the links to the bugs. The first one seems more relevant than the second one.

Comment: Yeah I think your best bet is to just not allow changes to the listview during rotation.

Comment: If you could reproduce easily I would suggest printing the value for 'getItemCount' before all calls to 'notify*' ... you might discover your item count does not match your assumptions.

Comment: @karolrvn  It's also amazing to me that almost every article on RecyclerViews has its focus on creating a list, but none on saving the list. It does no good to create a beautifully crafted/valuable list (say a big list of songs I want to download) and then have the list literally be destroyed if I navigate away from the list with the single press of the back button. Why wouldn't saving state code be a requirement for creating every RecyclerView list just like the other requirements: the adapter, the layoutmanager, onCreateViewHolder, onBindViewHolder and getItemCount?  Am I missing something?

Comment: Rule to remember is: "always notify...() immediately after changing the dataset, and make sure to call it from the same thread".

Comment: @AJW You should focus on "saving the list" when you receive items to display in the list. Your list should use an in-memory copy of already-persisted data as its data source. Taking the attitude of 'saving the list' with the back button is too late - if the app crashes, or battery dies, etc. Look into, for example CursorAdapter.

Comment: If you called `adapter.setHasStableIds()`, just remove this call. It worked for me.

Comment: @KarolDepka Did you find the definitive answer?

Comment: Feels like a thread-safety issue

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier That should be the accepted answer!

Comment: I added 10,000 items to my adapter and was able to reproduce the crash pretty consistently.

Answer (score 269):

I had a (possibly) related issue - entering a new instance of an activity with a RecyclerView, but with a smaller adapter was triggering this crash for me.

`RecyclerView.dispatchLayout()` can try to pull items from the scrap before calling `mRecycler.clearOldPositions()`. The consequence being is that it was pulling items from the common pool that had positions higher than the adapter size.

Fortunately, it only does this if `PredictiveAnimations` are enabled, so my solution was to subclass `GridLayoutManager` (`LinearLayoutManager` has the same problem and 'fix'), and override `supportsPredictiveItemAnimations()` to return false :

```
/**
 * No Predictive Animations GridLayoutManager
 */
private static class NpaGridLayoutManager extends GridLayoutManager {
    /**
     * Disable predictive animations. There is a bug in RecyclerView which causes views that
     * are being reloaded to pull invalid ViewHolders from the internal recycler stack if the
     * adapter size has decreased since the ViewHolder was recycled.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean supportsPredictiveItemAnimations() {
        return false;
    }

    public NpaGridLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    public NpaGridLayoutManager(Context context, int spanCount) {
        super(context, spanCount);
    }

    public NpaGridLayoutManager(Context context, int spanCount, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, spanCount, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, and disabling predictive animations doesn't cause you to lose the animations all together.  Bravo.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir! Worked instantly with LinearLayoutManager, probably saving me days.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solution is worked with LinearLayoutManager.

Comment: I think this guy deserve we build a statue in honour of his precious help...
It's one of the worst documented issue on the web, but it seems lots of dev encounter this issue...
I just wonder *how* did you find it could be skipped if PredictiveAnimations are false, @KasHunt ? Because, the stacktrace is very unclear...

Comment: Another way to get rid of this is to call notifyDataSetChanged() immediately after setting new adapter on RecyclerView.

Comment: Not working for me! I do not change the Adapter every time new data is set (because the items are added to the existing collection). So I just call notifyItemInserted normally but the exception is still thrown. `notifyDataSetChanged` sounds that it should work but still the same.

Comment: Is there a corresponding bug ticket on Android Support Library or Google Code?

Comment: Wasted 2 days with this bug. Its almost 3 years since bug was reported but not solution from Google yet.

Comment: It also solves my problem I have a issue with firebase recycler adapter. Whatever manager you can use the main key is this one `@Override
    public boolean supportsPredictiveItemAnimations() {
        return false;
    }`

Comment: Please attach the link to the bug report in Google's issue tracker.

Comment: What will this cause the RecyclerView? Any disadvantages?

Comment: I want to believe the solution is this simple. But in RecyclerView.java class RecyclerView.LayoutManager, here is the base impl: `public boolean supportsPredictiveItemAnimations() {
            return false;
        }` and it's not overriden in LinearLayoutManager. Am I missing something? Support lib v26.

Comment: I know angel... and he have given answer of this question. are you able to explain why really this is happening?

Comment: Wasted 3 days with this bug. still now not fixed yet. any other solutions ?

Comment: Anybody knows, how to fix that without this hack? Because notifyDatasetChanged was dropped in favor of DiffUtil

Comment: I added this to my code and it seems to have reduced the number of crashes but they didn't fully go away. Are there other reasons I would get `Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 184`?

Comment: worked for me with ListAdapter, setting recyclerView.itemAnimator = null

Comment: This solves same porblem, when populating my adapter when notifying changes ;)

Comment: I was also facing the same issue while using `PagingDataAdapter` and `GridLayoutManager` and this is the only solution that worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For me I had to add above solution for **LinearLayoutManager** and  also **notifyDataSetChanged()** right after when I set Adapter to RecyclerView. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Always needed in 2024. Many thanks.

Answer (score 114):

In my case (delete/insert data in my data structure) I needed to clear recycle pool and then notify data set changed!

`mRecyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: I don't normally say this, BUT THANK YOU SO MUCH. I have tried EVERYTHING to fix this crash which happens sporadically when I'm moving a bunch of items on the list around in rapid order. I've spent literally probably a full week on trying to solve this issue. I walked away from it for a couple of months to try to give my brain a chance to approach it differently, then found this on my first Google attempt. Bless you!

Comment: why do you have to do this?

Comment: That's a pretty heavy operation that sort of defeats the purpose of recycling views.

Comment: @gjsalot So if I use this, can it cause some problems?

Comment: Where I have to write this code if I am using MVVM model.?

Answer (score 34):

Use `notifyDataSetChanged()` instead `notifyItem...` in this case.

Comment: In some cases this is the way to go. I had a situation where I replaced all my items, but I wasn't being honest with the adapter, only telling it I had inserted some new items (notifyItemRangeInserted), without first telling it I had also removed items. The adapter then expected there to be more items then there actually were. If using any of the adapter's notify methods expect notifyDataSetChanged, such as notifyItemRangeRemoved / Inserted / Updated, the caller has the full responsibility of telling the adapter *exactly* what was changed, or you may end up with this "inconsistent state".

Comment: This is not a solution at all.

Comment: This is not the way to go. If this works that means you just messed up the range for `notifyItem...` and correcting that will start working instead of re-rendering all the items.

Comment: @Ranjan RecyclerView doesn't "re-rendering all the items", it just renders what is on the screen ("visible")

Answer (score 26):

I had the same issue with `RecyclerView`
So I just notified the adapter about data set change right after the list cleared.

```
mList.clear();
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

mList.addAll(newData);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 20):

This error occur when the list in adapter clear when user scrolling which make position of item holder changing, lost ref between list and item on ui, error happen in next 
**"notifyDataSetChanged"** request.

Fix:

Review your update list method. If you do something like

```
mainList.clear();
...
mainList.add() or mainList.addAll()
...
notifyDataSetChanged();

===> Error occur
```

How to fix. Create new list object for buffer processing and assign again to main list after that

```
List res = new ArrayList();
…..
res.add();  //add item or modify list
….
mainList = res;
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Thanks to [Nhan Cao](https://medium.com/@nhancv/android-fix-java-lang-indexoutofboundsexception-inconsistency-detected-invalid-item-70e9b3b489a2) for this great help :)

Answer (score 15):

I solved this by delaying the `mRecycler.setAdapter(itemsAdapter)` till after adding all the items to the adapter with `mRecycler.addAll(items)` and it worked. No idea why i did that to begin with, it was from a library's code that I looked over and saw those lines in the "wrong order", I'm pretty sure this is it though, please if someone can confirm it explain why it's so? Not sure if this is a valid answer even

Comment: I think this is the solution, once i delayed the adapter it was fine i believe... now it pops up when set adapter in UI thread and adding items to it.

Comment: I used `swapAdapter(adapter, true)` instead of `setAdapter(adapter)` and it helped.

Answer (score 14):

I have same issue .It was occur when I was scrolling fast and calling API and updating data.After trying all things to prevent crash , I found solution.

```
mRecyclerView.stopScroll();
```

It will work.

Comment: This is a workaround not a fix. You are forcing it to stop the scroll. Bad UX

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO : Adapter need to set position and if you continue scrolling recylerview, adapter can't set data which is the cause of the crash. It's not bad UX

Comment: make sense. Stopping scroll is not bad ux since data refresh happening.

Comment: Thanks. It should be the accepted answer @AnandSavjani

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem but not exactly the same. In my case at 1 point I was clearing the array that was passed to the recyclerview

```
mObjects.clear();
```

and not calling notifyDataSetChanged, as I did not want the recyclerview to immediately clear the views. I was re-filling the mObjects array in AsyncTask.

Answer (score 8):

For me, it worked after adding this line of code:

```
mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
```

Comment: this is not a fix in most cases, if you want animation you have te rewrite your adapter code and find your errors in notifying changes

Comment: It works fine for me.I'm using real adapter so I can't control the flow and I enabled windowActivityTransitions in a style that what cause this issue thanks man you save my day.

Answer (score 6):

I am altering data for the `RecyclerView` in the background `Thread`. I got the same `Exception` as the OP. I added this after changing data:

```
myRecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks man! this is the only answer that makes sense from an Android development point of view.

Comment: While I have also solved with the help of `view.recycler_view.post`, I used `notifyItemInserted`. In my case it has already been UI thread.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I was updating the items and calling `notifyDataSetChanged` in a non-UI thread.  Most of the time it worked, but when a lot of changes happened quickly, it'd crash.  When I did, instead, basically

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        changeData();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

then it stopped crashing.

Answer (score 5):

My problem went away after I modified my `Adapter` implementation to use a copy of the items array instead of a reference. The `setItems()` method is called each time we have new items to show in the `RecyclerView`.

Instead of:

```
private class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemHolder> {
     private List<MyItem> mItems;  

    (....)

    void setItems(List<MyItem> items) {
        mItems = items;
    }
}
```

I did:

```
void setItems(List<MyItem> items) {
    mItems = new ArrayList<>(items);
}
```

Comment: This will solve the problem, but wont it take up twice the original memory?

Comment: @MiguelA.Gabriel this will effect performance? for example in my case i am updating recylerview's array too frequently 
so currently i am doing this `suggestionsRecyclerView.swapAdapter(new CandidatesAdapter(mSuggestions), true);
`  and this is my constructor  `public CandidatesAdapter(List<String> suggestionsList) {
            this.suggestionsList = new ArrayList<>(suggestionsList);
        }`

Comment: @mateen-chaudhry It probably will. You'll need to test it in your case and decide, or try using another of the proposed solutions. As I said, it is only a workaround and it works for me in my case.

Answer (score 5):

This is only solution which worked for me even trying many from above solutions.

1.) Intilization

```
CustomAdapter scrollStockAdapter = 
         new CustomAdapter(mActivity, new ArrayList<StockListModel>());
list.setAdapter(scrollStockAdapter);
scrollStockAdapter.updateList(stockListModels);
```

2.) Write this method in adapter

```
public void updateList(List<StockListModel> list) {
    stockListModels.clear();
    stockListModels.addAll(list);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

stockListModels -> this list is which you are using in adapter .

Comment: Not complete enough to understand what you are actually doing. If you have just created an adapter, you don't have to delete anything - how can there be anything in it?

Answer (score 4):

I've faced with the same situation.
And it was solved by adding codes before you clear your collection.

`mRecyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().clear();`

Answer (score 4):

In my case I just removed line with `setHasStableIds(true);`

Comment: But HasStableIds(true) improves the performance of the Rv, is there any alternative solution?

Comment: Actually I think it could be due to different reasons, so there could be different solutions to this problem based on what is the root cause.

Comment: @Sreekanth Karumanaghat You only can set stable Ids if they are stable.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
notifyDataSetChanged()
```

instead

```
notifyItemRangeInserted(0, YourArrayList.size())
```

in this case.

Comment: but this is not good for performance right? notifyItemRangeInserted is better, the problem does not lie here

Answer (score 3):

You only need to clear your list on `OnPostExecute()` and not while doing `Pull to Refresh`

```
// Setup refresh listener which triggers new data loading
        swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {

                AsyncTask<String,Void,String> task = new get_listings();
                task.execute(); // clear listing inside onPostExecute

            }
        });
```

I discovered that this happens when you scroll during a **pull to refresh**, since I was clearing the list before the `async task` , resulting to  `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected.`

```
        swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
        //TODO : This is very crucial , You need to clear before populating new items 
        listings.clear();
```

That way you won't end with an inconsistency

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this nasty stack trace with the new Android Architecture Components recently. Essentially, I have a list of items in my ViewModel that are observed by my Fragment, using LiveData. When the ViewModel posts a new value for the data, the Fragment updates the adapter, passing in these new data elements and notifying the adapter that there have been changes.

Unfortunately, when passing in the new data elements to the adapter, I failed to account for the fact that both the ViewModel and the Adapter would be pointing to the same object reference! Meaning that if I update the data and call `postValue()` from within the ViewModel, there's a very small window where the data could be updated and the adapter not yet notified!

My fix was to instantiate a fresh copy of the elements when passed in to the adapter:

`mList = new ArrayList<>(passedList);`

With this super easy fix you can be ensured your adapter data will not change until right before your adapter is notified.

Answer (score 3):

Using `ListAdapter (androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter)` call `adapter.submitList(null)` before calling `adapter.submitList(list)`:

```
adapter.submitList(null)
adapter.submitList(someDataList)
```

Comment: I am also using ListAdapter, but if we submitList(null) and then the actual data list then we are not really utilizing the benefits of ListAdapter

Answer (score 3):

This exception raised on API 19, 21 (but not new). In Kotlin coroutine I loaded data (in background thread) and in UI thread added and showed them:

```
adapter.addItem(item)
```

Adapter:

```
var list: MutableList<Item> = mutableListOf()

init {
    this.setHasStableIds(true)
}

open fun addItem(item: Item) {
    list.add(item)
    notifyItemInserted(list.lastIndex)
}
```

For some reason Android doesn't render quick enough or something else, so, I update a list in `post` method of the `RecyclerView` (add, remove, update events of items):

```
view.recycler_view.post { adapter.addItem(item) }
```

This exception is similar to "Cannot call this method in a scroll callback. Scroll callbacks mightbe run during a measure & layout pass where you cannot change theRecyclerView data. Any method call that might change the structureof the RecyclerView or the adapter contents should be postponed tothe next frame.": [Recyclerview - cannot call this method in a scroll callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42944005/recyclerview-cannot-call-this-method-in-a-scroll-callback).

Comment: Absolutely the same issue with loading data via RxJava.

Answer (score 3):

extends LinearLayoutManager and catch this error

```
public class NoCrashLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

    public NoCrashLinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NoCrashLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    public NoCrashLinearLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        try {
            super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can reproduce this crash in the following way

1. Clear adapter items `list.clear()`. (Do not call notify*** methods)
2. Scroll recycler view.

So I assume this crash happens when you remove items from the list and scroll without calling notify methods

Answer (score 2):

It also can be related with setting the adapter multiple times at the same time. I had a callback method which was triggered 5-6 times at the same time and I was setting the adapter in that callback so RecycledViewPool couldn't handle with all of those datas contemporaneously. It's a fat chance but you better check it out anyway.

Comment: yes same problem.. But solution? You give the reason only.. How to fix?

Comment: @RanjithKumar, Kindly share your way to resolve the above issue. I resolved it using mRecyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().clear(); before notifyDataSetChanged and using synchronized block around update function of adapter

Comment: can you please take a look at my code i think my problem is like yours can you help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50213362/updating-recycler-view-from-handlerthread?noredirect=1#comment87443498_50213362

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was trying to **change my adapter contents on a background thread but called notify* on the main/ui thread.**

**That is not possible!** The reason why notify is forced to main thread is that the recyclerview wants you to edit your backing adapter on the main thread, even on the same call stack.

To solve the problem make sure that every operation to your adapter as well as every notify... call is made on the **ui/main thread**!

Comment: adding items to the list in your adapter should be done on a background thread and call notify on postexecute. adding of data in ui thread makes the app freeze for some millisecond or seconds if adding many data

Comment: agreed with @dionellorera, it should be made clear that a "change in adapter contents" specifically means modifying any data directly, whether primitive values, properties of objects, or objects themselves

Answer (score 2):

Just remove all views of your layout Manager before notify. like:

```
myLayoutmanager.removeAllViews();
```

Comment: It works. I had problem with scroll load and tab change.

Answer (score 2):

I've just fixed the same issue. I had a `RecyclerView.Adapter` with `setHasStableIds(true)` set to avoid items blinking.

I was using a duplicatable field in `getItemId()` (my model has no `id` field):

```kt
override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    // Error-prone due to possibly duplicate name.
    return contacts[position].name.hashCode().toLong()
}
```

**`getItemId()` should return a unique id for each item**, so the solution was to do it:

```kt
override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    // Contact's phone is unique, so I use it instead.
    return contacts[position].phone.hashCode().toLong()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this problem may happen when you try clearing your list, if you are going to clear your data list especially when you are using pull to refresh try to use a boolean flag, initialize it as false and inside OnRefresh method make it true, clear your dataList if flag is true just before adding the new data to it and after that make it false.

your code might be like this

```
 private boolean pullToRefreshFlag = false ;
 private ArrayList<your object> dataList ;
 private Adapter adapter ;

 public class myClass extend Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener{

 private void requestUpdateList() {

     if (pullToRefresh) {
        dataList.clear
        pullToRefreshFlag = false;
     }

     dataList.addAll(your data);
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged;


 @Override
 OnRefresh() {
 PullToRefreshFlag = true
 reqUpdateList() ; 
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a same issue previously. Finally found a workaround for that

What i do is to notify adapter that item has removed and then notify adapter data set range changed

```
 public void setData(List<Data> dataList) {
      if (this.dataList.size() > 0) {
          notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, dataList.size());
          this.dataList.clear();
      }
      this.dataList.addAll(dataList)
      notifyItemRangeChanged(0, dataList.size());

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue and just figured it out. I hard-coded a few examples for a test case but didn't ensure they each returned a unique ID and that caused the below crash for me. Fixing the IDs resolved the issue, hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 1):

For fix this issue just call notifyDataSetChanged() with empty list before updating recycle view.

For example

```
//Method for refresh recycle view

    if (!hcpArray.isEmpty())
```

hcpArray.clear();//The list for update recycle view

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Not a solution.

Comment: @Milha I didn't get any other solution to fix the crash issue. But the above solution is worked for me.   If it is not a solution the tell me the proper fix.

Comment: It depends. You can try using DiffUtil — a general-purpose tool for updating RecyclerView contents.

Answer (score 1):

i once got the error too:

**Cause:** I was trying to update a Recycler View from an Async task while simultaneously trying to get old deleted viewHolders;

**Code:** I generate data at the press of a button, logic as follows

1. Clear the last items in the recycler view
2. Call async task to generate data
3. OnPostExecute Update the Recycler view and NotifyDataSetChanged

**Problem:** Whenever i scroll fast before generating my data i get

> Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 20(offset:2).state:3

**Solution:** instead of clearing the RecyclerView before generating my data, i instead leave it and then Replace it with the New Data, the Call NotifyDatasetChanged, as shown below;

```
       @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Objects> o) {
            super.onPostExecute(o);
            recyclerViewAdapter.setList(o);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

Comment: can you please take a look at my code i think my problem is like yours [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50213362/updating-recycler-view-from-handlerthread?noredirect=1#comment87443498_50213362)

Answer (score 1):

Lint gave me an advice concerning inconsistency: 
I wrote (onBindViewHolder()):

```
pholder.mRlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        doStuff(position);
                    }
                });
```

which had to be replaced by :

```
pholder.mRlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        doStuff(pholder.getAdapterPosition());
                    }
                });
```

Run both codes in your code and then run Lint for the full explaination!!

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason for this crash.

Reloading data while recyclerview is still scrolling.

So, try recyclerview.stopScroll() before reloading your data again.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error when `DiffUtil.calculateDiff()` method was used incorrectly. In my case wrong list was passed to `MyCallback()`. To make sure it works correctly follow the code:

```
val oldList = adapter.getData() // get old list
val result = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(MyCallback(oldList, newList)) // calculate difference
adapter.setData(newList); // set new list to adapter
result.dispatchUpdatesTo(adapter); // dispatch updates immediately

class MyCallback(
    private val oldList: List<...>,
    private val newList: List<...>
): DiffUtil.Callback() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This should be the most correct answer - to add DiffUtil in RecyclerView.Adapter or use ListAdapter (which has built-in diffutil).

Answer (score 0):

I found that 
setting 
mRecycler.setLayoutFrozen(true);
in the onRefresh method of the swipeContainer.

solved the problem for me.

```
swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new   SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            orderlistRecycler.setLayoutFrozen(true);
            loadData(false);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a nasty bug.

To handle my item click, I used an implementation of the `RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener` similar to the solution found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick).

After many times of refreshing the `RecyclerView`'s datasource and clicking an item, this `IndexOutOfBoundsException` would crash my application. When an item is clicked, the `RecyclerView` internally goes looking for the correct underlying view and gives back it position. Checking out the source code, I saw that there were some `Tasks` and `Threads` scheduled. To cut the story short, basically it's just some illegal state where two datasources are intermixed and not synchronized and the whole thing goes wild.

Based on this, I removed my implementation of the `RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener` and simply caught the click on the `ViewHolder` of the `Adapter` myself:

```
public void onBindViewHolder (final BaseContentView holder, final int position) {

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick (View view) {

        // do whatever you like here
      }
    });

}
```

This might not be the best solution, but a crash-free on for now.. Hopefully this will save you some time :).

Comment: Creating a new object every time onBind gets called will result in a lot of objects that are going to be garbage collected and the user might experience freezing.

Answer (score 0):

add_location.removeAllViews();

```
            for (int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++)
            {
                add_location.addView(new HolderDropoff(AddDropOffActivtity.this,add_location,arrayList,AddDropOffActivtity.this,this));
            }
            add_location.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: first remove view, then add placeholder view and then refresh adapter

Answer (score 0):

Sorry For late but perfect solution:
when you try to remove a specific item just call notifydatasetchange()
and get these item in bindviewholder and remove that item and add again to the last  of list and then chek list position if this is last index then remove item.
basically the problem is come when you try to remove item from the center. if you remove item from last index then there have no more recycling and also your adpter count are mantine (this is critical point crash come here) and the crash is solved the code snippet below  .

```
 holder.itemLayout.setVisibility( View.GONE );//to hide temprory it show like you have removed item

        Model current = list.get( position );
        list.remove( current );
        list.add( list.size(), current );//add agine to last index
        if(position==list.size()-1){// remove from last index
             list.remove( position );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Very late response, but this may help someone on the feature.

Make sure that your onStop or onPause methods aren't clearing any of your lists

Answer (score 0):

The problem occured on me when I had not recoginized I did call two times with different threads simultaneously .

> notifyDataSetChanged

one from sqlite load function one from after calling function

Answer (score 0):

One way I managed to fix this (in a Kotlin app with architecture components) was by setting `if (recyclerView.adapter == null) recyclerView.adapter = MyAdapter(datasource)` after I fetched the data from the Repository. Apparently it might have something to do with async issues with the suspend functions in the repository because when I fetch data for the first time when starting the activity, it calls the REST API since there is no data in the db, and everything goes smoothly, but after that, that same query cannot be made again, causing a crash.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got this exception

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder

None of the answers above are worked in my case. Because I was updating/changing an existing item in the adapter but I used

```
myAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position)
```

Instead, I should use this

```
myAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position)
```

Note: We should use `notifyItemInserted()` when we insert an item and we should use `notifyItemChanged()` when we update an item in the adapter.

Comment: That's strange. I also confused both methods one time, but it didn't lead to the exception. It sometimes didn't update a list correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers are disabling animations or creating new copies of data which is an overkill in my opinion. They do work but they don't address the root cause of the issue. In my case it was due to using DiffUtils in a wrong way. In the `areItemsTheSame(old, new)` method I did not properly implement the equality check, that, in turn cased the adapter to be notified by `notifyItemRangeInserted()` even though the same number of items are in the new list. So pay close attention to how you implement the DiffUtils callbacks!

Comment: How could it be possible? Are you writing in Java (not Kotlin with data-classes)?

Comment: @CoolMind I was using Kotlin data classes and when you have another object as a property in the data class the equality check of data classes will not call equality check recursively

Answer (score 0):

If notifyItemChanged(int position), notifyItemInserted(int position)
Use instead of each other This problem occurs when you want to update the item use notifyItemChanged and when you want to add the item use notifyItemInserted

Answer (score 0):

Updated RecyclerView to newest 1.2.1 version. Aaand Magic happend! Couldn't break my app anymore :)
So.. try to replace old version number with the newest one in your gradle file

```
dependencies {
    ...
    // RecyclerView
    def recyclerview_version = "1.2.1"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$recyclerview_version"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one recycler views sharing the same adapter, then this error pops-up so to avoid this error create separate adapters for those recycler views.
This makes the recycler view to have unshared pools which stops the adapters to populate them when not required.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm using `DiffUtil.calculateDiff` for recycler view items, which has a race condition while updating items. I calculate data diff in background threads pool and update it in UI thread. If 2 data come, and the first data is set to adaptor between the timing that the second diff is calculated and set, the crash happens.

For example, say we have original item list A, new data B, and new data C:

1. B-diff = calculated (A, B)
2. C-diff = calculated (A, C)
3. set(B-diff)
4. set(C-diff)

The C-diff is actually incorrect since A has been updated, so if the items count decreases, recyclerview would animate on invalid positions. Not just crashes, the items may not be updated at all (or unncessary update) due to incorrect diff index.

Changing to `AsyncListDiffer` resolved the issue for me since it drops the first data if the second data comes too early.

reference (it describes the issue but gives another solution (updating data in order)): https://jonfhancock.com/get-threading-right-with-diffutil-423378e126d2

Answer (score 0):

i also had same problem since i was using different layout when dataset was  empty:-

while adding first item try

`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

then continue with

```
adapter.notifyItemChangedAtPosition(position)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `setHasStableIds(true)` you must be sure all dataset items has different ids, otherwise that error may be occur.

For example:

```
//This is our mock dataset which has FooItem type items
val dataset = listOf<FooItem>(items)

class FooItem {

    //here your variables

    private var id : Long = 0L

    //you can handle different ids at high accuracy like;
    fun getItemId() : Long {
        if (id == 0L) {
            id = abs(Random.nextLong(2, Long.MAX_VALUE))
        }
        return id
    }

}


//Then go back your adapter and set adapter item id below like
override fun getItemId(position: Int) = dataset[position].getItemId()
```

With this way, you will no need to close recyclerview animations and notify all dataset.

Answer (score 0):

On my case this approach helps to solve the problem .

```
val currentSize = mList.size
mList.clear()
notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, currentSize)

mList.addAll(newData)
mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mList.size - 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved the issue, adding items one by one when it gets new data. I use this function inside adapter.

```
public void add(Data item) {
        if(!params.contains(item){
           params.add(item);
           notifyItemInserted(getItemCount() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in my case , this solve my issue

```
rv.setAdapter(null);
rv.setItemAnimator(null);
```

PS: my problem ocur when i do seache filter in my recyclerview adapter

Answer (score -2):

If anyone is having the same issue, I overrided these two methods in my adapter, it worked perfectly.

```
        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
            return position.toLong()
        }
    
        override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
            return position
        }
```