# Recycler view Array index outof bound Incossitency Error while SwipetoRefresh and recycler scrolling same time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, indexoutofboundsexception, swiperefreshlayout

i am using 23.1.1 RecyclerView, when swipe to refresh is started and in that case when i am scrolling my RecyclerView it will crash and gives me Error

Here is my ErrorLog,

```
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{39e0644b position=6 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent}
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:4251)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4382)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4363)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1961)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1370)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1333)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1161)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollVerticallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1018)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1492)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:2416)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8476)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2092)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2407)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2407)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2407)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2407)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2407)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2407)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2407)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2407)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2407)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2407)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2407)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2407)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2369)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1719)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2752)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2330)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8671)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4193)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4059)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3604)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:36
```

These error only happens when i am using swipe to refresh layout.

In  onBindViewHolder method in adapter i am calling an event for loadmore data when last item visible

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        if(position == data.size() -1 && data.size() >= AppConstants.LIST_PAGE_SIZE){

            EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new LoadMoreDataEvent(getPageIndex()));
        }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

after clear list and when i am trying to notify adapter i getting this error , These is a bug in recycler view .  i just clear list and set adapter null and its working.

```
list.clear();
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: We'll need your code if you want help.

Comment: yes facing same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the list has cleared out there would be problem in getting correct position for running background task, so when you clear a recycle view  before notifydatasetchange at that time don't use it. Use this:

```
mAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, YourArrayList.size())
```

instead of

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may came across bug in recycler view. it is already posted here - [RecyclerView: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220771/recyclerview-inconsistency-detected-invalid-item-position)

for bug tracking you can check [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77232) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=1&q=77846&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&id=77846)

Comment: @androidnoobdev please answer this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434071/android-support-v4-widget-swiperefreshlayout-working-but-it-is-not-visible

Comment: @HammadNasir you have already answered it so what else i can do.