# Recycler View: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder

Tags: android-recyclerview

Recycler View Inconsistency Detected error, coming while scrolling fast or scrolling while loading more items..

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.pratap.endlessrecyclerview, PID: 21997
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{56a082c position=40 id=-1, oldPos=39, pLpos:39 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent}
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:4251)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4382)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4363)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1961)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1370)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1333)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:562)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2864)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1445)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.access$400(RecyclerView.java:144)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:282)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

**Adapter**

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private final int VIEW_ITEM = 1;
    private final int VIEW_PROG = 0;

    private List<Feed> mFeed;
    // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
    // before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
    private boolean loading;
    private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;

    public DataAdapter(List<Feed> feeds, RecyclerView recyclerView) {

        mFeed = feeds;

        if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {

            final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView
                .getLayoutManager();

            recyclerView
                .addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                        int dx, int dy) {
                        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                        totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                        lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager
                            .findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                        if (!loading
                            && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                            // End has been reached
                            // Do something
                            if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                                onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                            }
                            loading = true;
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mFeed.get(position) == null ? VIEW_PROG : VIEW_ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
        int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
        if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

            vh = new StudentViewHolder(v);
        }
        else {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.progress_item, parent, false);

            vh = new ProgressViewHolder(v);
        }
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof StudentViewHolder) {

            Feed singleStudent= (Feed) mFeed.get(position);
            ((StudentViewHolder) holder).tvName.setText(singleStudent.getTitle());
            ((StudentViewHolder) holder).student= singleStudent;
        } else {
            ProgressViewHolder.PROGRESS_BAR.setIndeterminate(true);
        }
    }

    public void setLoaded() {
        loading = false;
    }

    public void  addFeed(Feed feed) {
        mFeed.add(feed);
        //mFeed.addAll(0, (Collection<? extends Feed>) feed);
        notifyItemInserted(mFeed.size());
        //notifyItemRangeInserted(0,mFeed.size());
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        //notifyItemInserted(mFeed.size());
        //setLoaded();
        //notifyItemInserted(mFeed.size());
    }

    public void removeAll(){
        mFeed.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFeed.size();
    }

    public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
        this.onLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
    }

    public static class StudentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView tvName;

        public Feed student;
        public StudentViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);

            //tvEmailId = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvEmailId);
        }
    }

    public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //public ProgressBar progressBar;
        public static ProgressBar PROGRESS_BAR;
        public ProgressViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            PROGRESS_BAR = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            //  progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    private TextView tvEmptyView;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private DataAdapter mAdapter;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private RestManager mManager;
    private List<Feed> mFeed;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    protected Handler handler;
    private int currentPage=1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        tvEmptyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout= (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        //studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        mFeed = new ArrayList<Feed>();
        handler = new Handler();
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Android Students");

        }
        mManager = new RestManager();

        // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        // use a linear layout manager
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        // create an Object for Adapter
        mAdapter = new DataAdapter(mFeed,mRecyclerView);

        // set the adapter object to the Recyclerview
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        //   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        loadData(false);

        //        if (mFeed.isEmpty()) {
        //            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //            tvEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //
        //        } else {
        //            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //            tvEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //        }

        mAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                //add null , so the adapter will check view_type and show progress bar at bottom
                mFeed.add(null);
                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mFeed.size() - 1);

                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //   remove progress item
                        mFeed.remove(mFeed.size() - 1);
                        // mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(mFeed.size());
                        //add items one by one
                        int start = mFeed.size();
                        currentPage++;

                        Log.d("CurrentPage", String.valueOf(currentPage));
                        Call<Results> listCall = mManager.getFeedApi().getAllFeeds(1);

                        listCall.enqueue(new Callback<Results>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call<Results> call, Response<Results> response) {
                                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                                if (response.isSuccess()) {
                                    if (response.body() != null) {
                                        Results feedList = response.body();

                                        // List<Results> newUsers = response.body();

                                        Log.d("Retrofut", String.valueOf(feedList));

                                        for (int i = 0; i < feedList.results.size(); i++) {
                                            Feed feed = feedList.results.get(i);
                                            // mFeed.add(feed);
                                            mAdapter.addFeed(feed);
                                            //                                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                                            //mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mFeed.size());

                                        }
                                        //    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Call<Results> call, Throwable t) {
                                Log.d("Retrofut", "Error");
                                mFeed.remove(mFeed.size() - 1);
                                mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(mFeed.size());

                                mAdapter.setLoaded();
                                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                            }
                        });

                        //        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
                        //            studentList.add(new Student("Student " + i, "androidstudent" + i + "@gmail.com"));
                        //
                        //        }

                        mAdapter.setLoaded();
                        //or you can add all at once but do not forget to call mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
    }

    // load initial data
    private void loadData(final boolean removePreData) {

        Call<Results> listCall = mManager.getFeedApi().getAllFeeds(1);

        listCall.enqueue(new Callback<Results>() {

                             @Override
                             public void onResponse(Call<Results> call, Response<Results> response) {

                                 if (response.isSuccess()) {
                                     if (response.body() != null) {
                                         //  if(removePreData) mAdapter.removeAll();
                                         Results feedList = response.body();
                                         Log.d("Retrofut", String.valueOf(feedList));

                                         for (int i = 0; i < feedList.results.size(); i++) {
                                             Feed feed = feedList.results.get(i);
                                             // mFeed.add(feed);
                                             //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                             mAdapter.addFeed(feed);
                                         }

                                         mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                                     }
                                 }
                             }

                             @Override
                             public void onFailure(Call<Results> call, Throwable t) {
                                 Log.d("Retrofut", String.valueOf(t));
                                 mFeed.remove(mFeed.size() - 1);
                                 mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(mFeed.size());
                                 mAdapter.setLoaded();
                                 mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                             }
                         }
        );

        //        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        //            studentList.add(new Student("Student " + i, "androidstudent" + i + "@gmail.com"));
        //
        //        }

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        mFeed.clear();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        loadData(true);
        currentPage=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same Error its coming because I've use endless recycler as my data get to the last position it doesn't get the item count like if you set it get 27 item count in every scroll at last may be you don't get 27 items so its occur then after that as i get whats the problem just created logic that if I mod(%) list.size() by item i'm getting if it equal to 0 just use notifyItemrangeInserted otherwise notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Is there any way to reproduce this? I am getting this crash in my production app but cannot reproduce it locally

Comment: if you produce locally use low end device with 1GB ram

Comment: If you get this error after making a change to a Room entity that should only affect another activity that's not the one where this error occurs, chances are when you rebuilt the project, it used a layout code cache that did not adapt to these changes and you will need to delete data from app from the Android system settings

Answer (score 72):

> put this line along with setting recyclerView. issue was fixed by
> setting ItemAnimator to null for RecyclerView.

in kotlin

```kotlin
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recyclerView.itemAnimator = null
```

in java

```java
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
```

Comment: this solves my problem, but what is the reason of crashing if itemAnimator is not null

Comment: OK, this solves my problem too.

Comment: this removes the animation when adding or removing items

Comment: Thank you! it's 2022 now and your answer is still relevant

Comment: This is working

Comment: Wow, this saved me a lot of time.  Thank you!

Comment: Can anyone explain the reason of current behaviour?

Comment: I think there is no need to disable the entire animation.Just disable PredictiveAnimations.  Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33985508/9061224

Comment: Works in 2023, but why?

Comment: Always needed in 2024, and if you need animation nevertheless solution is https://stackoverflow.com/a/33985508/9061224. Thanks @MarGin

Answer (score 46):

It looks similar with known Android [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77846#c10). There is an ugly, but working approach:

```
public class WrapContentLinearLayoutManager extends GridLayoutManager {
    //... constructor
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        try {
            super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

            /* This only happens with notifyItemRangeChanged(), when there indeed is an inconsistency. */
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "IndexOutOfBoundsException: " + e.getMessage());
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Filterable should use notifyItemRangeRemoved() & notifyItemRangeInserted()");
        }
    }
}


mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new WrapContentGridLayoutManager(getContext(), spanCount));
```

For me it works without any side-effect.

Comment: App is not crashing after using this but the error is still there, What's the exact reason for this error ?

Comment: things work .. but could you explain the reason of crash?

Comment: this is a really bad idea, cathcing the exception and silencing it... https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37030377#comment9 @Angad Tiwari

Comment: @payyd what is spanCount?

Comment: @VijayRajput number of columns in custom GridLayoutManager, as I remember that piece of code, anyway its unrelated to topic. 
BTW, looks like this bug was fixed.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of **RecyclerView: 26.0.2** and this bug still will show up sometimes so I suppose they didn't fixed it.

Comment: @paynd what code ? It's a simple RecyclerView with an adapter which sets data from an ArrayList of strings

Comment: it supposed to be "extends GridLayoutManager".

Comment: Is there any way to reproduce this crash, because we are getting this crash in production but not able to reproduce it locally

Comment: Is there a reason why you call the class WrapContentLinearLayoutManager? Why WrapContent? Does the fix only work for RecyclerViews with wrap_content height/width?

Comment: My auto generated constructor in Xamarin.Android is  WrapContentLinearLayoutManager(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) ....How to initialize this with context and spanCount?

Comment: You save my day, I was struggling from 3 days to fix this.

Comment: Info - Samsung device only get this crash

Answer (score 46):

This issue is a known bug of RecyclerView. The best solution is, clear the list every time before refresh RecyclerView.

For fix this issue just call notifyDataSetChanged() with empty list before updating recycle view.

For example

```
//Method for refresh recycle view

if (!yourList.isEmpty())

yourList.clear(); //The list for update recycle view

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I am falling this problems recyclerview LoadMore items

Comment: @AhamadullahSaikat did you get answer of it ?

Comment: I'm working with a recyclerview, adapters and fragment and this is working for me. I just add a method on my adapter to check from fragment if my list is empty.
`boolean isEmpty(){return mylist.isEmpty;}` and then in my fragment call `myadapter.isEmpty()`

Comment: Well this is odd, clearing the list upon refresh is actually what CAUSED the issue for me. However I wasn't calling notifyDataSetChanged. If anyone is going to use this solution, DEFINITELY make sure you update.

Comment: It works! You saved my day after one hour of useless researches!

Comment: it shouldn't be used because adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
load all data, since if you have 1000 datas it will load it every time you datas are updated.

Answer (score 15):

Use this to refresh a RecyclerView

```
items.clear(); //here items is an ArrayList populating the RecyclerView
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
items.addAll(list);// add new data 
adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, items.size);// notify adapter of new data
```

`

Comment: thanks bro this Answer is 100% work for me . when my recyclerview is inside fragment . 
Thank you very much .

Answer (score 10):

I had similiar issue, and also this solution has helped me, after I've added new item to my RV:

```
recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case I was doing it as  `notifyItemInserted(position);`
That caused me this issue then i used as and it worked perfectly.`notifyItemRangeInserted(startIndex,endIndex);`

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can try this before refresh the adapter:

```
dataList.clear(); 
patrolListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in this line of code:

```
 mFeed = feeds;
```

you are assigning `mFeed` to the caller's instance `feeds` so whenever the caller changes it's variable (may be adding, clearing or removing items), your local `mFeed` will change

try to change to

```
mFeed.addAll(feeds);
```

don't forget to initialize `mFeed` to any list tat fits your needs like `mFeed = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was using `RecyclerView` from `Firebase UI`. Initially, the logic to initialize the `RecyclerView` was in `onCreate()`. To fix, I put the logic in `onResume()` and seems to be working for me. I had this error when going back to the `Activity` which had the `RecyclerView`. So, everytime the `Activity` screen is refreshed, the new data is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when scrolling fast through my endless/paging `RecyclerView`. The root of my problem came from the fact that I had a “header” item at the beginning of the list, this header item was not a part of the data source, it was just inserted at the beginning of the `adapter` list. So when scrolling fast and adding new pages of items to the `RecyclerView` `Adapter` and notify the `adapter` that new data had been inserted, I was not taking into account the additional header item, thus making the size of the adapter’s list wrong... and causing this exception...

So in short, if you’re using a header/footer in our `RecyclerView` adapter make sure you take it into account when updating the adapters data.

**Example:**

```
public void addNewPageToList(List<MyData> list)
{   //
    // Make sure you account for any header/footer in your list!
    //
    // Add one to the currentSize to account for the header item.
    //
    int currentSize = this.adapterList.size() + 1;
    this.adapterList.addAll(list);
    notifyItemRangeInserted(currentSize, this.adapterList.size());
}
```

**Edit:** 
I guess you could always just use the adapter method `getItemCount()` to get the size, instead of getting the size from the “data list” and adding to it. Your `getItemCount()` method should already be taking into account any additional headers/footers/etc that you have in your list.

Answer (score 1):

put this line along with setting recyclerView. issue was fixed by setting ItemAnimator to null for RecyclerView.

```
in kotlin
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.itemAnimator = null
```

Answer (score 1):

For my case in adapter there was `notifyItemRangeInserted` and I replaced it with `notifyItemRangeChanged`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the recyclerview from mikepenz. And any update to the items using .set(item) was causing this issue.

For some reason, setting recylerView.itemAnimator = null, resolved the issue. This is a known android bug.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Removing all views from RecyclerView helped me:

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
layoutManager.removeAllViews();
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was I wasn't posting notifyDatasetChanged when the data set changed as I implemented incremental search.

I had a list that was filtered based on what the user searched in the search widget.  For each item in the list, I was making a remote request, and when I got the result back, I was updating that particular cell.

I had to do both notifies for the recycler view to work

Filter the original data set then post the dataset change

```
this.searchResultTable?.post {
    this.searchResultTable?.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

After receiving response, post notifications again

```
this.searchResultTable?.post {
    this.searchResultTable?.adapter?.notifyItemChanged(index, updateDataHashMap)
}
```

You have to post updates rather than sending notifiy messages directly in order to prevent the recycler view from crashing when the update comes in before the view is laid out.

Another important gotcha is that when you post the individual updates after the remote response, you have to make sure that the list the user currently sees is the list that existed when the requests were sent.