# Custom Sectioned RecyclerView Inconsistency detected if invoking notifyItemRemoved(position);

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm implementing a `SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter`. I know that there are many great libraries for this task, but before quit I'd like to enjoy the try. So please, before shoot at me consider that this is a prototype and every suggestion about improvements will be welcome.

Here the implementation. The concept is simple, every `pojo` that wants to be *sectioned* must implement the `Sectioned` interface with just one method that return the title of section. Then a `LinkedHashMap` will keep track of the sections vs indices.

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;


abstract
public class SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter<
    HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
    ValueViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
        extends
            RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public interface Sectioned {
        String getSection();
    }

    static final private String TAG = "sectioned-rv";

    private static final int TYPE_NORMAL     = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_HEADER     = 0;

    final
    private List<Sectioned>  mObjects;

    final
    private Object   mLock;

    final
    private LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> sectionsIndexer;

    /* Removed for now, not sure if will be more elegant/better or worst
    private final RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver mDataSetObserver = new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            calculateSectionHeaders();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            onChanged();
        }
    };
    */
    private boolean         mNotifyOnChange = true;


    public SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter() {
        super();
        mLock = new Object();
        sectionsIndexer = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        mObjects = new ArrayList<>();
        setHasStableIds(true);
    }

    public void changeData(List<? extends Sectioned> data) {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            mObjects.clear();
            if (data != null)
                mObjects.addAll(data);
            calculateSectionHeaders();
        }

        if (mNotifyOnChange) notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void removeItemAt(int position) {
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
        if (viewType == TYPE_NORMAL) {
            int index = getSectionForPosition(position);
            synchronized (mLock) {
                mObjects.remove(index);
                calculateSectionHeaders();
            }
            if (mNotifyOnChange) notifyItemRemoved(index); //<- Crash
            // if (mNotifyOnChange) notifyDataSetChanged(); //<- Fine 
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            mObjects.clear();
            sectionsIndexer.clear();
        }

        if (mNotifyOnChange) notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void sort(Comparator<? super Sectioned> comparator) {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            Collections.sort(mObjects, comparator);
            calculateSectionHeaders();
        }

        if (mNotifyOnChange) notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    /**
     * Interceptor before the sections are calculated so we can transform some computer data into human readable,
     * e.g. format a unix timestamp, or a status
     *
     * By default this method returns the original data for the group.
     * @param groupData original group name
     * @return the transformed group name
     */
    protected String getCustomGroup(String groupData) {
        return groupData;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mObjects.size() + sectionsIndexer.size();
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
            return onCreateHeaderViewHolder(parent);
        }

        return onCreateValueViewHolder(parent);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
        if (viewType == TYPE_NORMAL) {
            Sectioned item = getItem(position);
            if (item == null) {
                Log.v(TAG, "getItem(" + position + ") = null");
                return;
            }

            onBindValueViewHolder((ValueViewHolder)holder, position);
        }

        else {
            final String group = sectionsIndexer.get(position);
            onBindHeaderViewHolder(group, (HeaderViewHolder) holder);
        }
    }

    public Sectioned getItem(int position) {
        if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_NORMAL) {
            return mObjects.get(getSectionForPosition(position));
        }
        return mObjects.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) { return position; }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position == getPositionForSection(position)) {
            return TYPE_NORMAL;
        }
        return TYPE_HEADER;
    }

    abstract
    protected HeaderViewHolder onCreateHeaderViewHolder(ViewGroup parent);

    abstract
    protected void onBindHeaderViewHolder(String group, HeaderViewHolder viewHolder);

    abstract
    protected ValueViewHolder onCreateValueViewHolder(ViewGroup parent);

    abstract
    protected void onBindValueViewHolder(ValueViewHolder holder, int position);

    private int getPositionForSection(int section) {
        if (sectionsIndexer.containsKey(section)) {
            return section + 1;
        }
        return section;
    }

    private int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        int offset = 0;
        for (Integer key : sectionsIndexer.keySet()) {
            if (position > key) {
                offset++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        return position - offset;
    }

    private void calculateSectionHeaders() {
        int i = 0;

        String previous = "";
        int count = 0;

        sectionsIndexer.clear();

        for (Sectioned item: mObjects) {
            final String group = getCustomGroup(item.getSection());
            if (!previous.equals(group)) {
                sectionsIndexer.put(i + count, group);
                previous = group;

                Log.v(TAG, "Group <" + group + "> at position: " + (i + count));

                count++;
            }

            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine but I noticed that when I remove an item calling `removeItemAt(position)` If I call `notifyItemRemoved(index);` the app will crash with this exception:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{855a1d3 position=3 id=4, oldPos=4, pLpos:4 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent}
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:5041)                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5172)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5153)
```

If I call `notifyDataSetChanged();` after removing the item, everything works fine.

So I'm just curious why this happens. Debugging with breakpoints to [RecyclerView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.java#4800) implementation I noticed that the cause could be the check on:

```
holder.mPosition >= mAdapter.getItemCount()
```

but cannot see why the check fails if in my implementation `getItemCount` return this:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mObjects.size() + sectionsIndexer.size();
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: May help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220771/recyclerview-inconsistency-detected-invalid-item-position

Comment: Hi @Praveen thanks but that looks like as another type of "Inconsistency". Thansk anyway.

Comment: @Luca Sepe What is the benefit of using "synchronized (mLock)" for CRUD operations in the adapter?  I haven't come across its usage before and am wondering what the benefits are.