# recylcerview error onScrollStateChanged()

Tags: android, exception, android-recyclerview, onscrolllistener

My app contains a scrollview with search option(on actionbar),when scrolling the recyclerview without any keyword for search not creating any issues.But when i type any word in the search view and try to scroll the recyclerview ,app crashes.

logcat Error:-

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 5(offset:5).state:46
```

Activity.java:-

```
private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener recyclerViewOnScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {

        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        try {
            int visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
            int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
            int firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            if (isSearch) {
                isLastPage = false;
                jobArrayList.clear();

            }

            if (!isLoading && !isLastPage) {
                if ((visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition) >= totalItemCount
                        && firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0
                        && totalItemCount >= PAGE_SIZE) {

                    getDataFromWebServises("", start, "20", "scroll");

                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

void getDataFromWebServises(String search_key, String start, String count, final String type) {
    if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
        textNWError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        showSnackBar(getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet_connection));

    } else {
        textNWError.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        final String url = "webservice url";
        showProgressBar();
        isLoading = true;


        final JSONObject requestJsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            requestJsonObject.put("user_id", UserSingleton.getInstance().getUser().getUser_id());
            requestJsonObject.put("start", start);
            requestJsonObject.put("count", count);
            requestJsonObject.put("search_key", search_key);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        CustomRequest jsonObjReq = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, requestJsonObject,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        hideProgressBar();
                        isLoading = false;


                        try {

                            Gson gson = new Gson();
                            Type listType = new TypeToken<List<job>>() {
                            }.getType();

                            if (type.equals("top"))
                                jobArrayList.clear();




                            ArrayList<job> jobs = gson.fromJson(response + "", listType);
                            if (jobs != null) {
                                jobArrayList.addAll(jobs);

                                if (jobs.size() >= PAGE_SIZE) {
                                } else {
                                    isLastPage = true;
                                }
                            }


                            if (type.equals("scroll")) {

                                loadRecylcerview(jobArrayList);
                            } else if (type.equals("top")) {
                                setUpRecyclerView(jobArrayList);
                                String json = gson.toJson(jobArrayList);
                                pref.saveJobList(/*response.toString()*/json);
                            }


                        } catch (Exception e) {
   //                            Log.e("execp", e + "");
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                  Log.e("error", error + "");
                hideProgressBar();
                isLoading = false;

                showSnackBarNetworkError(0);
                NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
                if (networkResponse != null && networkResponse.statusCode == 403) {
                    // HTTP Status Code: 403 Unauthorized
                    logout();
                }
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                headers.put("User-Token", UserSingleton.getInstance().getUser().getUser_token());
                headers.put("User-Id", UserSingleton.getInstance().getUser().getUser_id());
                return headers;
            }
        };

        jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS, 10, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        MyVolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, url);
    }
}

  private void loadRecylcerview(ArrayList<job> arrayList) {

        start = String.valueOf(arrayList.size());

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(recyclerViewOnScrollListener);


}
      private void setUpRecyclerView(ArrayList<job> arrayList) {
    if (arrayList.size() == 0) {
        textEmpty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        textEmpty.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    start = String.valueOf(arrayList.size());

    mAdapter = new JobAdapter(arrayList, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    // Pagination
    if(!isSearch){
        if (isNetworkAvailable())
            recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(recyclerViewOnScrollListener);
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me to solve the issue.???

Comment: You need to notifyDataSetChanged and need to use updated datasource (array list) which came after sorting. At the time of scroll its referring to older  array list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220771/recyclerview-inconsistency-detected-invalid-item-position)

Comment: @Reena yes i have using notifyDataSetChanged .but no use,the error is still happening..