# updating recycler view from HandlerThread

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i am working on keyboard app and i am showing suggestion when user type something in this method i start a new `HandlerThread` and after when that thread finish its job i am posting to main thread update ui but on fabric i am getting lot of crashes but i could not find the reason and i can not  regenerate on my devices  this is my method which i am posting

this is my `HanlderThread` whenever i want to show suggestion updated

```
 private void showSuggestions(final String word) {

    mSuggestionHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    mSuggestionHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             if (!word.contains("'") && !word.isEmpty()) {
                getSuggestions(word);
            } else mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    setNextSuggestions();
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

this is getSuggestions method runing on non ui thread

```
    private void getSuggestions(String word) {

    Log.e("get:userDictSuggestions", word);

    List<String> dictSuggetions = (List) this.mDictionary.complete(word);
    if (dictSuggetions.size() > 18)
        dictSuggetions = dictSuggetions.subList(0, 17);



    userDictSuggestions.clear();
    userDictSuggestions.addAll(dictSuggetions);

    if (userDictSuggestions.size() > 0) {
        if (this.mOldSuggestions.size() > 0) {
            this.mOldSuggestions.clear();
        }
        this.mOldSuggestions.addAll(userDictSuggestions);
    }
    if (userDictSuggestions.size() < 18) {
        userDictSuggestions.addAll(this.mOldSuggestions);
    }
    mSuggestions = userDictSuggestions;

    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setSuggestions(mSuggestions, null, false, false);
        }
    });

}
```

and this is my show suggestion method

```
 private void setSuggestions(List<String> suggestions, boolean completions, boolean typedWordValid, boolean haveMinimalSuggestion) {
    if (this.mIsShowingHint) {
        setCandidatesView(this.mCandidateViewContainer);
        this.mIsShowingHint = false;
    }

        this.candidatesAdapter = new CandidatesAdapter(suggestions);
        this.suggestionsRecyclerView.setAdapter(this.candidatesAdapter);
        this.candidatesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

and i am getting these crashes

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 3(offset:3).state:34 android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{447a1378 VFED.... .F....ID 6,0-708,53 #7f0a0138 app:id/suggestions_recycler_view}, adapter:.keyboard.inputmethod.LatinIME$a@44ec2ef0, layout:android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager@447cb440, context:keyboard.inputmethod.LatinIME@41c40578
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5817)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3225)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16508)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5162)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1052)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16508)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1034)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16508)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5162)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16508)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5162)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16508)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5162)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16508)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5162)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16508)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5162)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16508)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5162)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16508)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5162)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2317)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16508)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1921)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5691)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5281)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:932)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:748)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220771/recyclerview-inconsistency-detected-invalid-item-position

Comment: and this links https://www.google.com/search?q=Fatal+Exception:+java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:+Inconsistency+detected.+Invalid+item+position+3(offset:3).state:34+android.support.v7.widget.Rec+site:stackoverflow.com&client=ubuntu&hs=Yz1&channel=fs&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixy9OawvPaAhXDQI8KHVqFCxYQrQIIMygEMAA&biw=1600&bih=727

Comment: @NileshRathod i checked this but i couldn't find any solution