# How to fix "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected."

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am calling a onClickListener() of textView which is inside my cardview, and showing the dialog fragment which has a ADD(positive) and Cancel(negative) buttons.

Everything is working fine and as I wanted. But problem is that when I press Cancel button and scroll the recyclerview it throws "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected." exception.

I don't know where the problem is I tried notifyDataSetChanged() but it caused another problem. I have been trying again and again but the problem still exists.

Here is the onBindVIewHolder() code.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    //GETTING THE EACH OBJECT OF EXPENSEDATA [CONTAINING EACH ROW FROM DB] 
      FROM ARRAYLIST
    ExpenseData ed = expenseDataArrayList.get(position);

    //GETTING VALUE OF CARDVIEW FROM ABOVE CONSTRUCTOR AND SETTING IT TO 
      cardView
    CardView cardView = holder.cardView;


    TextView edit = (TextView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.edit);
    edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            int pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            System.out.println("Position = "+pos);
            eddd = expenseDataArrayList.remove(pos);
            expName = eddd.getExpName(); expType = eddd.getExpType(); expAmt = eddd.getExpAmt();
            EditAddExpenseDialog editAddExpenseDialog = new EditAddExpenseDialog();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("expName",expName);
            args.putString("expType",expType);
            args.putDouble("expAmt",expAmt);
            editAddExpenseDialog.setArguments(args);
            editAddExpenseDialog.show(((Activity)context).getFragmentManager(), "update ima");

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: post your Expense dialog code well.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220771/recyclerview-inconsistency-detected-invalid-item-position

Comment: I just refreshed my fragment in the onDestroyView() method of my DialogFragment. It worked for me