# RecyclerView: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-recyclerview

I've started getting this crash reported on Crashlytics. I have no idea how to reproduce it but it all appears to be code internal to the `RecyclerView`. I think this comes from a `RecyclerView` I have which never really changes. The user can refresh it but then all items are replaced and `notifyDataSetChanged` is called.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 5(offset:5).state:7
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4041)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3999)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1892)
       at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:419)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1301)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:534)
       at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:156)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2365)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:2709)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1160)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1877)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1653)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1160)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
       at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:907)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2325)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2031)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1191)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6233)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5296)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: Do you know which RecyclerView causes this? If so, please provide the adapter code for it

Comment: He got same crash. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827222/how-to-change-contents-of-recyclerview-while-scrolling

Comment: You are right, I must have not searched right. It just started happening after my 22.1 appcompat update so I'm guessing it is a bug.

Answer (score 7):

I have been facing this issue, I'm very tired searching for a solution. But I have found an answer which resolves this problem and no exception have been thrown out again.

```
public class MyLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager  {
    public MyLinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    public MyLinearLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsPredictiveItemAnimations() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        //override this method and implement code as below
        try {
            super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } }
```

I hope this answer will resolve your problem.

Comment: And to use the ablove class, where do I call it?

Comment: I have the same exception again even after using that class

Answer (score 0):

Create your own **LinearLayoutManager**.

**CustomLinearLayoutManager.java**

```
public class CustomLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsPredictiveItemAnimations() {
        return false;
    }

    public CustomLinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    public CustomLinearLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }
}
```

How to set **CustomLinearLayoutManager** on **RecyclerView**.

```
CustomLinearLayoutManager customLinearLayoutManager= new HPLinearLayoutManager(mContext);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(customLinearLayoutManager);
```

Hope this will save your time.

Comment: This causes the view to be empty.