# On scroll the RecyclerView getting exception : -" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 21"

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am using the `RecyclerView` with `Sqlite` in my app.
As i have load the `RecyclerView` from the `SQlite` and than after call service in background and try to notify the `RecyclerView` by `notifyDataSetChanged()` method but getting the unexpected exception while scrolling the `RecyclerView`( when `RecyclerView` is updating or notifying).

Please check my `setAdapter()` which i am using to notify and set the adapter on `RecyclerView`

```
  private void setAdapter() {

        if (adapter == null) {
            adapter = new EmojiAdapter(stickerArrayList, getActivity(), "Sticker", stickerIdArrayList);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            rvEmoji.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            rvEmoji.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            rvEmoji.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    }
```

I have tried all `RecyclerView.stopScroll()`, `RecyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().clear()` but problem is not short out

**Exception**

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 21(offset:21).state:32
>                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5546)
>                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5482)
>                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5478)
>                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2215)
>                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1542)
>                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1502)
>                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1316)
>                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollVerticallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1061)
>                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.run(RecyclerView.java:4769)
>                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
>                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
>                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
>                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
>                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5095)
>                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
>                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

There are alots of simliar question but i am not getting the expected result.Here is the link which i have visited before posting the question here.
[1. First link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220771/recyclerview-inconsistency-detected-invalid-item-position)
[2. Second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827222/inconsistency-detected-in-recyclerview-how-to-change-contents-of-recyclerview-w)
[3. Third link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458640/recyclerview-java-lang-indexoutofboundsexception-inconsistency-detected-inval)
[4. Forth link](https://github.com/janishar/PlaceHolderView/issues/34) 
[5. Fifth link](https://github.com/HabitRPG/habitica-android/issues/108) 
[6. Sixth link](https://github.com/CymChad/BaseRecyclerViewAdapterHelper/issues/431)

I have visited all the link and tried their best solutions , but it is not working for me..

I am using the following gradle version for the RecyclerView

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
```

Please check the Adapter class which i am using as follow:-

```
public class EmojiAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EmojiAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Activity activity;
    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<EmojiBean>> arrayList = new HashMap<>();
    private String sticker_emoji;
    private ArrayList<String> keyArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private RecyclerView rvItemCreation;
        private TextView txtStickerName, txtBy, txtCreator;
        private ImageView imgForward, imgDownload;

        private MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            rvItemCreation = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvItemCreation);
            txtStickerName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtStickerName);
            txtBy = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtBy);
            txtCreator = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtCreator);
            imgForward = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgForward);
            imgDownload = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgDownload);

            txtStickerName.setTypeface(Constant.setCustomFont(activity, "Montserrat-SemiBold.otf"));
            txtBy.setTypeface(Constant.setCustomFont(activity, "Montserrat_Regular.otf"));
            txtCreator.setTypeface(Constant.setCustomFont(activity, "Montserrat_Regular.otf"));

        }
    }


    public EmojiAdapter(HashMap<String, ArrayList<EmojiBean>> arrayList, Activity activity, String sticker_emoji, ArrayList keyArrayList) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.sticker_emoji = sticker_emoji;
        this.keyArrayList = keyArrayList;


    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.my_media_item, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {


        if (sticker_emoji.equalsIgnoreCase("Sticker")) {
            holder.imgForward.setImageResource(R.drawable.forward_icon);
        } else {
            holder.imgForward.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete_icon);
        }


        if (arrayList.size() > position) {
            MyCreationItemAdapter mAdapter = new MyCreationItemAdapter(arrayList.get(keyArrayList.get(position)), activity);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
            holder.rvItemCreation.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            holder.rvItemCreation.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            holder.rvItemCreation.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }


}
```

Please help me to short out from the problem.Thanks

> **Update**
>   What i have done to resolve this conflict that I have done disable user interface(Show some progress bar) while loading the data.

Comment: where is your adapter?

Comment: Do u need to see it also??..I will post as u will say

Comment: Yes, it will help me :D

Comment: Please check the question..i have edited it..and let me know

Comment: check your array list size before attaching it to adapter and inside adapter

Comment: try to add this in method.
`@Override
    public boolean supportsPredictiveItemAnimations() {
        return false;
    }`
May animation cause that error.

Comment: @ysl it is not problem..Concern is that while Recyclview is notifying by notifyDataChanged() and at the same time i am scolling the recyclview than this exception occured..Otherwise if i am not scrolling the recyclview while adpter is notifying than this exception not ocurred..Please check it once..Thanks

Comment: @DeepakOjha Where i need to use this code..Please let me know once

Comment: Are you updating the adapter from another thread, possible while the RecyclerView is mid animation? When does setAdapter() get called and from where?

Comment: i am updaing the recyclview with same thread :(

Comment: Did you solved yet?

Comment: Not yet...Have done with disable user interface while loading the data..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question with "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 6(offset:6).state".  This crash is show with pullrefrash , when you had loadmore the list is more than you first loaded . then you pulltorfrash new data and  clear the old list data ,at this moment you adapter’s data size is not more than you new data size.

Comment: You can try this way: when you refresh  use adapter.notifyDataChanged.and when you loadmore data use adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(list.size,list.size);

Answer (score 1):

Try commenting this line of code:

```
rvEmoji.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

Check if it works now. If it does then the error you faced is because the PredictiveAnimations are enabled. To use your code with animation you'll have to subclass the specific layout manager that you are using and override the **supportsPredictiveItemAnimations()** method and return false.

```
@Override 
public boolean supportsPredictiveItemAnimations() { 
       return false; 
}
```

For detailed understanding have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33985508/8450534).