# IndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to populate data in recyclerview from two json arrays in a one json object

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-recyclerview, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting a Json Object from the server and that Json object contained two Json arrays. I know how to put data in to the recyclerview in a json array. But i don't know how to put two json array data to the recyclerview. One Json array contained rep, name, name1. Here name means name1's id(codeID). Next array contained customer(codeID) and coll (name and customer are same). I am generating the json using two different tables. I am populating the name1 in the recyclerview now successfully.

What I want is to get the name1 and its corresponding coll value. For example each row need to represent name1 and name1's coll value. Some name1 has no coll values(null). In that case coll textview need to be empty. Sometimes two arrays sizes(length) are not equal.

This is my Json.

```
{
  "feed": [
    {
      "rep": "503",
      "name": "30000216",
      "name1": "GERLINE TYRE HOUSE (BRANCH)"
    },
    {
      "rep": "503",
      "name": "30000217",
      "name1": "*G.L.P.K.Liyanage(ISURU ENTERP"
    },
    {
      "rep": "503",
      "name": "30000218",
      "name1": "**Kamal Motor Stores"
    },
    {
      "rep": "503",
      "name": "30000223",
      "name1": "T.Thamotherempillai & Sons"
    },
    {
      "rep": "503",
      "name": "30001037",
      "name1": "Iynkarn Motors(Distributor)"
    },
    {
      "rep": "503",
      "name": "30001074",
      "name1": "Northern Province MPCS FED"
    },
    {
      "rep": "503",
      "name": "30001131",
      "name1": "Kishor Tyre House"
    },
    {
      "rep": "503",
      "name": "45000012",
      "name1": "R.G.M.Transporters"
    }
  ],
  "feeddd": [
    {
      "customer": "30000220",
      "coll": "92820.00"
    },
    {
      "customer": "30000222",
      "coll": "1784348.61"
    },
    {
      "customer": "30000224",
      "coll": "2661442.57"
    },
    {
      "customer": "30000225",
      "coll": "15580475.00"
    },
    {
      "customer": "30001302",
      "coll": "698968.93"
    }
  ]
}
```

YourDealerListFragment class

```
private void getJsonRequest() {
        progressView.start();

        final SQLiteHandler sqLiteHandler = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        Cursor cr = sqLiteHandler.getData(sqLiteHandler);
        cr.moveToFirst();

        do {
            repNo = cr.getString(0);
        } while (cr.moveToNext());
        cr.close();

        CustomJsonObjectRequest request = new CustomJsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_JSON_DEALER_LIST, hashMap, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {


            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                progressView.stop();

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                    if (jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("feed")) {
                        dealerList = parseJsonResponse(response);
                        dlAdapter.setDealertList(dealerList);

                        JSONArray arrayDealerColl = response.getJSONArray("feeddd");
                        ArrayList<DealerCollection> dealerColList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < arrayDealerColl.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject obj3 = arrayDealerColl.getJSONObject(i);
                            String dealerName = obj3.getString("customer");
                            String dealerCollection = obj3.getString("coll");

                            DealerCollection dealerColl = new DealerCollection();
                            dealerColl.setDealerName(dealerName);
                            dealerColl.setDealerCollection(dealerCollection);

                            dealerColList.add(dealerColl);
                            dlAdapter.setDealerCollectionList(dealerColList);

                        }

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Dealers Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hashMap.put("repNo", repNo);
                return hashMap;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(request);
        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(15 * 1000, 0,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    }


    private ArrayList<SuggestGetSet> parseJsonResponse(JSONObject response) {
        ArrayList<SuggestGetSet> groupList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (response != null || response.length() > 0) {

            try {

                JSONArray arrayDelaers = response.getJSONArray(KEY_FEED_NAME);

                for (int i = 0; i < arrayDelaers.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject currentObject = arrayDelaers.getJSONObject(i);
                    String rep = currentObject.getString(KEY_REP_ID);
                    String name = currentObject.getString(KEY_REP_NAME);
                    String dealerId = currentObject.getString(KEY_DEALER_ID);

                    SuggestGetSet delaers = new SuggestGetSet();
                    delaers.setId(rep);
                    delaers.setName(name);
                    delaers.setDealerId(dealerId);

                    groupList.add(delaers);

                }
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), productList.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return groupList;
    }
```

My Adapter class

```
public class DealerListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DealerListAdapter.ViewHolderDealerList> {
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    public Context mcontext;
    private List<SuggestGetSet> dealerArrayList;
    private List<SuggestGetSet> originalDealerArrayList;
    private List<DealerCollection> dealerCollectionArrayList;
    Typeface type;
    private static String selectedRepId, selectedDealerId, selectedDealerName;

    public DealerListAdapter() {
    }

    public DealerListAdapter(Context context) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        type = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "helvr.ttf");
    }

    public static String getDealerName() {
        return selectedDealerName;
    }

    public static String getDealerID() {
        return selectedDealerId;
    }

    public static String getRepID() {
        return selectedRepId;
    }

    public DealerListAdapter(ArrayList<SuggestGetSet> dList, Context context) {
        this.mcontext = context;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.dealerArrayList = new ArrayList<>(dList);
        this.originalDealerArrayList = new ArrayList<>(dList);
        type = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "helvr.ttf");
    }

    public void setDealertList(ArrayList<SuggestGetSet> dealerAList) {
        this.dealerArrayList = dealerAList;
        originalDealerArrayList = new ArrayList<>(dealerAList);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, dealerArrayList.size());
    }

    public void setDealerCollectionList(ArrayList<DealerCollection> dealerColList) {
        this.dealerCollectionArrayList = dealerColList;
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, dealerCollectionArrayList.size());
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolderDealerList onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dealer_list_layout, parent, false);
        ViewHolderDealerList viewHolderDealerList = new ViewHolderDealerList(view);
        return viewHolderDealerList;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderDealerList holder, int position) {
        final SuggestGetSet model = dealerArrayList.get(position);
        holder.bind(model);

        final int pos = position;

        final DealerCollection model_two = dealerCollectionArrayList.get(position);
        holder.bind_two(model_two);

        holder.dealerName.setText(dealerArrayList.get(position).getName());

        holder.dealerName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                selectedDealerId = dealerArrayList.get(pos).getDealerId();
                selectedRepId = dealerArrayList.get(pos).getId();
                selectedDealerName = dealerArrayList.get(pos).getName();
            }
        });

        if (dealerArrayList.get(position).getDealerId() == dealerCollectionArrayList.get(position).getDealerName()) {
            holder.dealerCol.setText(dealerCollectionArrayList.get(position).getDealerCollection());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dealerArrayList.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolderDealerList extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView dealerName, dealerCol;

        public ViewHolderDealerList(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            dealerName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.yourDelaerName);
            dealerCol = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDelaerCollection);
        }

        public void bind(SuggestGetSet model) {
            dealerName.setText(model.getName());
        }

        public void bind_two(DealerCollection model) {
            dealerCol.setText(model.getDealerCollection());
        }

    }

    public void setFilter(List<SuggestGetSet> models) {
        dealerArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        dealerArrayList.addAll(models);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

My LogCat

```
04-29 14:06:53.529 11709-11709/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 10, size is 10
  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
  at com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat.adapters.DealerListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DealerListAdapter.java:83)
  at com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat.adapters.DealerListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DealerListAdapter.java:21)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5471)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5504)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4741)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
  at android.support.v7.widget.LayoutState.next(LayoutState.java:100)
  at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.fill(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:1538)
  at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:657)
  at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:592)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2906)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3283)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1695)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1866)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1687)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.intern
```

Comment: This bug is still not fixed in 23.1.1, but a common workaround would be to catch the exception.refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827222/how-to-change-contents-of-recyclerview-while-scrolling

Comment: can you suggest me a way to add second array list items to corresponding name in the recyclerview?

Comment: is dealerCollectionArrayList object size is same as dealerArrayList object size...??

Comment: @SarithaG they can be either same or not

Comment: Their sizes should be same...otherwise you should write the condition which I have updated as answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please Write this condition instead of fetching Object from index position:

```
 if (dealerCollectionArrayList.size < position) {
        final DealerCollection model_two = dealerCollectionArrayList.get(position);
        holder.bind_two(model_two);

        if (dealerArrayList.get(position).getDealerId() == dealerCollectionArrayList.get(position).getDealerName()) {
            holder.dealerCol.setText(dealerCollectionArrayList.get(position).getDealerCollection());
        }
    }else {
         //Set not available or something
    }
```