# Android RecyclerView: IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a problem with my RecyclerView, I learnt [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827222/inconsistency-detected-in-recyclerview-how-to-change-contents-of-recyclerview-w#answer-26832214) that bug had been fixed and that I should make sure that I'm inserting data on main thread and calling apropriate notify. I did that, but I am still getting this exception.

**onLoadFinisher method** (I am using loaders to load more data)

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data)
{
    switch (loader.getId())
    {
        case UP_LOADER_ID:
            Log.d("Adapter", "Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            days.put(firstDate, data);
            notifyItemRangeInserted(0, data.getCount()+1);
            loadingUp = false;
            break;

        case DOWN_LOADER_ID:
            days.put(lastDate, data);
            notifyItemRangeInserted(getItemCount(), data.getCount()+1);
            loadingDown = false;
            break;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown loader id: " + loader.getId());
    }
}
```

**log**

```
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/Adapter: Thread: main
D/Adapter: Thread: main
D/Adapter: Thread: main
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: net.antilopa, PID: 6406
                  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{fa4fb40 position=42 id=-1497045600000, oldPos=21, pLpos:21 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached not recyclable(1) no parent}
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:5220)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5402)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5363)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5359)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2141)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1525)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1488)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:585)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3457)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3252)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3767)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16722)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can replace **getItemCount()** by **getItemCount()-1**, because getItemCount() returns number of counts but index value is getItemCount()-1.

```
 case DOWN_LOADER_ID:
        days.put(lastDate, data);
        notifyItemRangeInserted(data.getCount()-1, data.getCount()+1);
        loadingDown = false;
        break;
```

Comment: Thanks, it's true, but unfortunately I am still getting the same exception

Comment: @F. Korf You can use data.getCount()-1 then check

Comment: Yes I tried using getCount()-1 but I am still getting the same exception. Or check what?